# Merge two arrays alternating value in a functional programming approach

Tags: javascript, for-loop, functional-programming, array-merge

How can I merge two arrays in a functional programming approach?

Current

```
const result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {
  result.push(arr1[i]);

  if (i < arr1.length - 1) {
    result.push(arr2[i]);
  }
}
```

This works for I need it to do, but I’d like to see thoughts on my question. I have attempted a few different ways but this is what I think is the cleanest.

Comment: Should `if (i < arr1.length - 1) {` be `if (i < arr2.length - 1) {` ?

Comment: The technique of alternating values is also called "interleaving" (as in "interleave arrays") or "faro shuffling". The latter is shared terminology between playing card techniques (shuffling so you precisely get alternating cards) as well as mathematics where it describes the same thing but with sets/collections. You can find more hits using those terms, including [this Code Golf question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/82294/faro-shuffle-an-array).

Comment: You could use modulo arithmetic to alternate `push()`, ie `if (i % 2 === 0) result.push(arr2[i])`

Answer (score 0):

```
function alternatePush (arr1, arr2) {
  let myArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++){
      myArray.push(arr1[i]);
      myArray.push(arr2[i]);
    }
  return myArray;
}
alternatePush ([1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]);
```

Comment: Nice. What about the case where arr1.length !== arr2.length (missing items) Or when arr2.length > arr1.length (out of bounds for arr1).

Comment: This is the code that’s already in the question, minus a check that might be necessary.

Comment: If they are different lengths, the question goes back to the original post - how do you intend on alternating them? If one is 5 in length and the other 7, the longer one will have to double up at some point, or append the rest at the end.